# Called function result

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide

Here in main method I want to call `num` value from `number()` and `result` from `finger()`

So I can use them in main method by adding:

```
if (the sum was even) {
    print out even if (the user chose evens) { the user wins }
else { the computer wins }
```

Here is my Game class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        number();
        finger();
        /*
        if (the sum was even) {
            print out even if (the user chose evens) { the user wins }
        else { the computer wins } 
        */
    }

    public static void number() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Lets's play a Game \"Odd and Even\" " +
                "\nWhat is your name?\t ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Hi " + name +" Welcome to the Game, Please 
              choose (O)dds or (E)vens ?");
        String num = input.next();

        if (num.equalsIgnoreCase("O") || num.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
            if (num.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
                System.out.println(name + " has choosen Evens! The computer will be Odds");
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " has choosen Odds ! The Computer will be Even");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please choose the correct one");
        }
    }

    public static void  finger() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many fingers do you put out?\t");
        int fing = input.nextInt();

        Random ran = new Random();
        int computer = ran.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println("The Computer plays " + computer);

        int result = fing + computer;
        System.out.println(fing + " + " + computer + " = " + result);

        if (result % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" .........is Even!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("........ is Odd!");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you mean **return** `num` and **return** `result` from their respective methods, so they can be used in `main`.  [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) should help.

Comment: Yes i need to return num & result but how i tried hard but not coming. I make the methods as i return type but ends with error : ( num & result not declared ,Am using intelji)

Comment: Your example has `void` return type - see the linked tutorial from my original comment.